# Solving a 4x4 multiplicative puzzle "5040" in Prolog with clp(FD)

Tags: prolog, puzzle, clpfd

Today, I found a puzzle at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/the-5040-square:

> Fill a 4x4 grid with positive integers so that:
>
> Every cell has a different integer
>
> The product of the numbers in each row is 5040, and similarly for the columns
>
> [Source: This was an NPR weekly listener challenge, aired on 2005-10-09](http://www.taterenner.com/nprmps.htm)

Here's my first shot at solving the puzzle using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

m5040_(Mss,Zs) :-
   Mss = [[A1,A2,A3,A4],
          [B1,B2,B3,B4],
          [C1,C2,C3,C4],
          [D1,D2,D3,D4]],
   Zs = [A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2,B3,B4,C1,C2,C3,C4,D1,D2,D3,D4],
   Zs ins 1..sup,           % domain: positive integers
   5040 #= A1*A2*A3*A4,     % rows
   5040 #= B1*B2*B3*B4,
   5040 #= C1*C2*C3*C4,
   5040 #= D1*D2*D3*D4,
   5040 #= A1*B1*C1*D1,     % columns
   5040 #= A2*B2*C2*D2,
   5040 #= A3*B3*C3*D3,
   5040 #= A4*B4*C4*D4,
   all_different(Zs).       % pairwise inequality
```

Sample query:

```
?- m5040_(Mss,Zs), time(labeling([],Zs)).
% 416,719,535 inferences, 55.470 CPU in 55.441 seconds (100% CPU, 7512588 Lips)
Mss = [[1,3,16,105],[10,14,9,4],[21,8,5,6],[24,15,7,2]], Zs = [1,3,16,105|...] ;
...
```

My actual question is twofold:

1. How can I speed up the backtracking search process for one / for all solutions?
2. Which symmetries / redundancies could I exploit?

Comment: s(X) for separating core relation and labeling!

Comment: Out of `1..5040`, there are only 60 possible values! I.e. `Zs =[A,B], A*B#=5040, Zs ins 1..sup, setof(A,B^labeling([],Zs),As).`

Comment: Since you're dealing with products across rows and across columns, given one solution, then any transposition or rotation of that solution is also a solution, and any permutation of rows or columns of that solution are solutions. I'm still thinking about how to exploit those facts within the Prolog context...

Comment: @lurker: That's at best a factor of 8. (And my proposition even slows things down ...)

Comment: @falsethere a lot more than 8 total permutations of rows and columns, plus 4 different rotations. But, I do agree, there aren't a huge number.

Comment: Just measured: `A1 #< A4,A1 #< D1,A1 #< D4,A4 #< D1` gives a factor of 2.

Comment: @lurker: Above constraints reduce the set of solutions by a factor of 8. What else do you see for immediate symmetry (there must be some more, indeed)

Comment: @lurker. As there are no constraints on diagonals, how about something like `A1 #< A2, A2 #< A3, A3 #< A4` *plus* `A1 #< D1`?

Comment: @false. Are you suggesting something like `Zs ins 1..10\/12\/14..16\/18\/20..21\/24\/28\/30\/35..36\/40\/42\/45\/48\/56\/60\/63\/70\/72\/80\/84\/90\/105\/112\/120\/126\/140\/144\/168\/180\/210\/240\/252\/280\/315\/336\/360\/420\/504\/560\/630\/720\/840\/1008\/1260\/1680\/2520\/5040`? Looks kind of sparse to me!

Comment: @repeat: Yes, it slowed it down...

Comment: @false. If `A*B*C*D #= 5040` and `all_different([A,B,C,D])` hold, the minimum values that `A`, `B`, and `C` can take are `1`, `2`, and `3`. So `D #=< 840` holds...

Comment: @false. Guesswork: `ff` labeling (unlike `step` or `enum`) takes a substantial hit when working with sparse domains like the one above for `Zs`. So it may be worthwhile to do some static reordering before doing `labeling([enum],Zs)`, and not use `ff` for dynamic variable reordering.

Comment: Plus: What about `all_distinct/1` vs `all_different/1` (when working with the sparse domain of `Zs`)?

Comment: all_distinct seems to be a lot slower (on the 1..sup domain). I have 1,586,132,730 inferences vs 464,043,891 inferences

Comment: while it behaves slight on the sparse domain 1\/2\/3\/...\/840 (581,988,846 inferences vs 661,956,983 inferences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my inference counters (using your code) don't match yours... not sure why...
the first solution i get (with your code)

```
?- puzzle_5040.
% 464,043,891 inferences, 158.437 CPU in 160.191 seconds (99% CPU, 2928894 Lips)
[[1,3,16,105],[10,14,9,4],[21,8,5,6],[24,15,7,2]]
true
```

I thought that reducing the domain could speedup the result

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(ordsets)).
:- use_module(library(apply)).

m5040_(Mss,Zs) :-
    matrix(Mss),
    flatten(Mss, Zs),
    all_factors(Fs),
    make_domain(Fs, Dom),
    Zs ins Dom,
    all_distinct(Zs),
    maplist(m5040, Mss),
    transpose(Mss, Tss), maplist(m5040, Tss).

m5040([A,B,C,D]) :- 5040 #= A * B * C * D.
length_(L, Xs) :- length(Xs, L).

matrix(Mss) :-
    length_(4, Mss),
    maplist(length_(4), Mss).

factors(L) :-
    L = [A,B,C,D],
    5040 #= 1 * 2 * 3 * U,
    L ins 1..U,
    all_distinct(L),
    A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
    5040 #= A * B * C * D.

all_factors(AllFs) :-
    findall(L, (factors(L),label(L)), Fs),
    foldl(ord_union, Fs, [], AllFs).
```

but I was wrong, it was slower actually...

Since some time ago I tried CLP(FD) solving some [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/about), and in some cases I found it was slower than raw arithmetic, I arranged a program that doesn't use CLP(FD), but reduces the domain to make it manageable:

```
puzzle_5040_no_clp :- time(puzzle_5040_no_clp(S)), writeln(S).

puzzle_5040_no_clp(S) :-
    findall(F, factors(F), Fs),
    factors_group(Fs, G),
    once(solution(G, S)).

disjoint(A, B) :-
    forall(member(X, A), \+ memberchk(X, B)).

eq5040([A,B,C,D]) :-
    5040 =:= A * B * C * D.

factors([A, B, C, D]) :-
    5040 #= 1 * 2 * 3 * U,
    [A, B, C, D] ins 1..U,
    A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
    5040 #= A * B * C * D,
    label([A, B, C, D]).

all_factors(AllFs) :-   % no more used
    findall(L, factors(L), Fs),
    foldl(ord_union, Fs, [], AllFs).

factors_group(Fs, [A, B, C, D]) :-
    nth1(Ap, Fs, A),
    nth1(Bp, Fs, B), Ap < Bp, disjoint(A, B),
    nth1(Cp, Fs, C), Bp < Cp, disjoint(A, C), disjoint(B, C),
    nth1(Dp, Fs, D), Cp < Dp, disjoint(A, D), disjoint(B, D), disjoint(C, D).

/*
solution([A,B,C,D], S) :-
    maplist(permutation, [B,C,D], [U,V,Z]),
    transpose([A,U,V,Z], S),
    maplist(eq5040, S).
*/
solution(T0, [U,V,X,Y]) :-
    peek5040(T0, U, T1),
    peek5040(T1, V, T2),
    peek5040(T2, X, T3),
    peek5040(T3, Y, [[],[],[],[]]).

peek5040([A,B,C,D], [M,N,P,Q], [Ar,Br,Cr,Dr]) :-
    select(M,A,Ar),
    select(N,B,Br), M*N < 5040,
    select(P,C,Cr), M*N*P < 5040,
    select(Q,D,Dr), M*N*P*Q =:= 5040.

% only test
validate(G) :- maplist(eq5040, G), transpose(G, T), maplist(eq5040, T).
```

with this approach, getting all solutions

```
?- time(aggregate(count,puzzle_5040_no_clp,N)).
% 6,067,939 inferences, 1.992 CPU in 1.994 seconds (100% CPU, 3046002 Lips)
[[1,24,14,15],[3,21,10,8],[16,5,9,7],[105,2,4,6]]
% 111,942 inferences, 0.041 CPU in 0.052 seconds (79% CPU, 2758953 Lips)
[[1,24,10,21],[3,15,14,8],[16,7,9,5],[105,2,4,6]]
...
% 62,564 inferences, 0.033 CPU in 0.047 seconds (70% CPU, 1894080 Lips)
[[1,10,12,42],[15,28,3,4],[16,9,7,5],[21,2,20,6]]
% 37,323 inferences, 0.017 CPU in 0.027 seconds (65% CPU, 2164774 Lips)
[[1,14,12,30],[15,2,28,6],[16,9,5,7],[21,20,3,4]]
% 2,281,755 inferences, 0.710 CPU in 0.720 seconds (99% CPU, 3211625 Lips)
% 48,329,065 inferences, 18.072 CPU in 27.535 seconds (66% CPU, 2674185 Lips)
N = 354.
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the inference counter number(s) myself either. I repeated the tests with SWI 7.3.6 and patched the question accordingly---but the numbers are still not identical with CapelliC's...